# Reload ViewController by clicking on TabBarItem

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar, pushviewcontroller, tabbarcontroller

I'm kinda desperate right now :/
I have a Tab Bar Controller with 4 Items. In the 4. Tab I included a webView which shows a list of pdf's. If I open a PDF in the webView there is no way to go back to the main webView with the links. Is there a way by re-clicking the 4. TabBar to reload the View? If I change from the 3. to the 4. tabbar it works (viewWillAppear).

[image]

Someone told me, that the following method should work:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{
if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UIColor class]]) {
    //Try this if you're pushing the webView in another ViewController
    [viewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    //or access to your webView and call goBack();
}
```

}

but actually I have no idea in which file I should insert that method. (See print Screen)

Thanks a LOT in advance for your help guys!

Comment: Here is the similar question. There is a tutorial on how to reload the page, by clikcing on the tab.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709519/reload-uiview-when-pressing-tab-item-inside-initialized-view/9710060#9710060

Comment: Thanks! I read through the tutorial but actually I don't know where to add the described code? If you may can have look on the posted printScreen, do you know where i have to add the described implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Subclass `UITabBarController`

1.1. Cmd+N and create a new instance of NSObject class, and name it TabBarController

1.2. in `TabBarController.h` replace `NSObject` so that it reads `@interface TabBarController : UITabBarController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>`

1.3. in `TabBarController.m` add this:

```
- (id) init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (self) 
  {
    self.delegate = self;
  }
  return self;
}
```

1.4. and this

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController 
    didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
  // Is this the view controller type you are interested in?
  if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[MehrViewController class]])
  {
    // call appropriate method on the class, e.g. updateView or reloadView
    [(MehrViewController *) viewController updateView];
  }
}
```

1.5. In IB, Inspection, change the class of Tab Bar Controller to **your** `TabBarController` (instead of `UITabBarController`)

1.6. You also need to include `MehrViewController.h` in `TabBarController.m`

---

**Edit**

in MehrViewController.m  (as you posted in your question, assuming it has a webView)

> ```
> // An example of implementing reloadView
>     - (void)reloadView {
>        [self.webView reload];
>     }
> ```

Comment: Hey Canopus! Thank you a lot for your help! I think I almost got it, but sadly just almost, I'm getting a warning right now called: "Instance method '-reloadView' not found (return type defaults to 'id') what does that means? (Sorry to ask that simple questions...)
Following you will find a picture of the warning:
http://joelschmid.ch/daten/tabbarcontroller.tiff
What do I have to do?

Comment: @Schmid -reloadView is method that 'you' have defined in your MehrViewController. You may have a different method, for example -reloadMyWebView. By default, your MehrViewController doesn't have such method. In another word, you have to implement it yourself. I added an example of such implementation as an edit to the answer.

Comment: Hey @Canopus
I hope this is the last time I have to bother you! :-)
Can you have a look at the PrintScreens in the archive (http://joelschmid.ch/daten/PrintSrciAppReloadWebsite.zip). I think I did everything right, but when i clicked on the TabBarItem the second time the website (webView) doesn't reload. 
I really would like to reciprocate to you, if you can contact me on my private e-mail (see stackoverflow account).
Thanks in advance!!!